# derivative of $\lvert \sin(x) \rvert$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Can somebody explain me one step. I know that $f(x):=\lvert \sin(x)\rvert$ doesn't have derivative at $x \in S:=\{n\pi, n \in \mathbb Z\}$. But if I want to prove it with definition, then I have a problem on one step. So

$$\text{LHD}=\lim_{h \to 0_{h>0}}\frac{\vert \sin(n\pi-h)\rvert-\lvert \sin(n\pi)\rvert}{-h}=-\lim_{h \to 0_{h>0}} \Bigg \lvert \frac{\sin(h)}{h} \Bigg \rvert=-1.$$

So that this limit equals to $-1$, I know. But how did we get this (second limit)? Can somebody explain me?

Thank you for help!

Comment: The limit is in fact $-1$.

Comment: @Gary I edited, thank you. Do u know, how did we get this second limit?

Comment: $\sin(n\pi)=0$, and the addition formula.

Comment: @peek-a-boo thank you) You helped me not first time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that

\begin{equation*}
\left|\sin{(n\pi - h)}\right| = \left|\sin{(n\pi)}\cos{(h)} - \cos{(n\pi)}\sin{(h)}\right| = \left|0\cdot\cos{(h)} - (-1)^{n}\sin{(h)}\right| = \left|\sin{(h)}\right|
\end{equation*}

and that

\begin{equation*}
\sin{(n\pi)} = 0 \implies \left|\sin{(n\pi)}\right| = 0.
\end{equation*}

Also, for $h>0$, $-\left|h\right| = -h$. Then we can write that

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{\substack{h\to 0\\ h>0}}{\frac{\left|\sin{(n\pi - h)}\right|-\left|\sin{(n\pi)}\right|}{-h}} = -\lim_{\substack{h\to 0\\ h>0}}{\frac{\left|\sin{(h)}\right|}{\left|h\right|}} = -\lim_{\substack{h\to 0\\ h>0}}{\left|\frac{\sin{(h)}}{h}\right|}.
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 0):

We have $\sin(n\pi)=0$ and $|\sin(n\pi-h)|=|-\sin(-h)|=|\sin(h)|.$ Then the denominator is $-|h|$ when $h$ is negative and $|h|$ when h is positive. Hence, the left hand derivative is $-1$ and the right hand derivative is $1$.